# Sequelize find for multiple tables

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have tables with columns as stated below,

```
TABLE A
    COLUMN id
    COLUMN b-id
TABLE B
    COLUMN id
    COLUMN c-id
TABLE C
    COLUMN id
TABLE D
    COLUMN id
    COLUMN c-id
```

Now, I wanted to get all the D's for particular A.id

How to implement it using the sequelize models?

To be precise, I wanted to start with something like this

```
A.findOne({
    where: { id }
})
```

BUT, do not want to make multiple sync calls one after one.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to first define Models for each of the tables, and then set the associations between the Models. This will define the relationships that you can use in the query with the `include` property. Setting `required: false` will use a `LEFT JOIN` so that results are still returned from ModelA even when there is related row in ModelB, for example.

*Associations*

```js
// ModelA - ModelB - ModelC < ModelD
ModelA.hasOne(ModelB);
ModelB.hasOne(ModelC);
ModelC.hasMany(ModelD, { as: 'modelDs' });

// ModelD > ModelC < ModelB < ModelA
ModelD.belongsTo(ModelC);
ModelC.hasMany(ModelB, { as: 'modelBs' });
ModelB.hasMany(ModelA, { as: 'modelAs' });
```

*Query*

```
const modelA = await ModelA.findByPk(id, {
  include: {
    model: ModelB,
    include: {
      model: ModelC,
      include: {
        model: ModelD,
        as: 'modelDs',
        required: false,
      },
      required: false,
    },
    required: false,
  },
});

console.log(modelA.modelB.modelC.modelDs);
```